# How to calculate two different numpy array's values then put the result in a third array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays that I need to calculate to get the needed behaviour for the third array.

To start, here is the first two arrays:

```
[[2 0 1 3 0 1]
 [1 2 1 2 1 2]       # ARRAY 1
 [2 1 2 1 0 1]
 [0 2 0 2 2 3]
 [0 3 3 3 1 4]
 [2 3 2 3 1 3]]

[[0.60961197 0.29067687 0.20701799 0.79897639 0.74822711 0.21928105]
[0.67683562 0.14261662 0.74655501 0.21529103 0.14347939 0.42190162]
[0.21116134 0.98618323 0.93882545 0.51422862 0.12715579 0.18808092]    # ARRAY 2
[0.48570863 0.32068082 0.32335023 0.62634641 0.37418013 0.44860968]
[0.12498966 0.56458377 0.24902924 0.12992352 0.76903935 0.68230202]
[0.90349626 0.75727838 0.14188677 0.63082553 0.96360265 0.28694261]]
```

Where array1[0][0] will be used to subtract the the input value from array3[0][0], and then array2[0][0] will be used multiply the now subtracted value from array3[0][0] to give the new output of array3[1][0] (In other words, these calculations WILL get array3).

So for example, lets say the starting values of array3[0] are:

```
[[20,22,24,40,42,10],
  ....
```

For array3[0][0] (20), it needs to subtract 2 (coming from array1[0][0]), leaving the value with 18. The value 18 is then **NOW multiplied** by 0.60961197 (array2[0][0]) leaving a **NEW VALUE of 10.97**. **10.97 is now the NEW value of array3[1][0].**

If you were to move onto the next column, the process would be the same. You would take 22-0 = 22, then take 22 *  0.29067687 to create the new value for array3[1][1].

To provide a visual example, the completed process of this array for the first two lines would look something like this:

```
      [[20 22 24 40 42 10],
     [10.97  19.65 7.44 10.58 7.03],
      ....
```

I am trying to get this process continuing for the entire length of the first array ( and I guess second because they are the same). So for the next set, you would take 10.97-1 * 0.6768... = 6.74.. and so on for each index until it reaches the end.

I'm quite stuck on what to do for this, I had tried a for loop but I feel like there may be a lot  more a an efficient way of doing this in numpy.

**I sincerely appreciate the help**, I know this isn't easy (or maybe it will be!). This will kick start what will be a fairly lengthy project for me.

Thank you very much!

**Note:** If numpy arrays are not a good way to solve this problem and lets say lists are better, I am more than willing to go that route. I'm just assuming with most of numpy's functions this will be easier.

Comment: Could you add the array3?

Comment: Add array3 to what? Like finish the array?

Comment: The starting values of array3

Comment: If you don't want to do analytical math, you can simply do `array3[i+1]=(array3[i]-array1[i])*array2[i]` within `for i in range(len(array1))`

Comment: Calculating the starting values of array3 won't really change anything @DanielMesejo, because array3's functionality is just to get the result of the calculation of array1 and 2

Comment: Where does the value 22 in your example comes from? You use them to obtain the values of array3, so they must come from somewhere

Comment: Oh I see sorry, array3 had those values initially. So I just picked those numbers randomly and put them into a list. So then that whole first row of numbers is just used to calculate the remaining numbers (so the next row of numbers). So in other words, there is no calculation for the first row, it's just the next rows.

Comment: Also (20 - 2) * 0.60961197 gives 10.97301546?

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I messed up on my math here. Your right with the formula. I'll edit it

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

arr1 = np.array([[2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1],
                 [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                 [2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1],
                 [0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3],
                 [0, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4],
                 [2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3]])

arr2 = np.array([[0.60961197, 0.29067687, 0.20701799, 0.79897639, 0.74822711, 0.21928105],
                 [0.67683562, 0.14261662, 0.74655501, 0.21529103, 0.14347939, 0.42190162],
                 [0.21116134, 0.98618323, 0.93882545, 0.51422862, 0.12715579, 0.18808092],
                 [0.48570863, 0.32068082, 0.32335023, 0.62634641, 0.37418013, 0.44860968],
                 [0.12498966, 0.56458377, 0.24902924, 0.12992352, 0.76903935, 0.68230202],
                 [0.90349626, 0.75727838, 0.14188677, 0.63082553, 0.96360265, 0.28694261]])

arr3 = np.random.randint(5, 30, size=(6, 6))

result = (arr3 - arr1) * arr2

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[ 5.48650773  6.97624488  3.72632382  9.58771668  8.97872532  5.2627452 ]
 [ 6.7683562   2.99494902 19.41043026  2.79878339  2.00871146 10.96944212]
 [ 4.85671082  6.90328261  9.3882545  13.88417274  0.89009053  4.702023  ]
 [12.14271575  1.28272328  9.05380644  8.76884974  2.99344104  1.34582904]
 [ 3.1247415   1.12916754  3.23738012  2.98824096 11.53559025 17.0575505 ]
 [17.16642894  8.33006218  2.55396186 10.09320848 17.3448477   5.7388522 ]]
```

If applied to the data from your example, you get:

```
arr3 = np.array([20, 22, 24, 40, 42, 10])
result = (arr3 - arr1[0]) * arr2[0]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[10.97301546  6.39489114  4.76141377 29.56212643 31.42553862  1.97352945]
```

Note that in the second example I just use the first row from `arr2` and `arr3`.

Comment: So would it be possible to take the output you gave for my example, apply the calculation formula and then keep repeating that process for the length of array1?

Comment: @LandonG no need to, the first example applies to all rows. The `-` and `*` operators are element-wise in numpy

Comment: But then shouldn't the result ( if i'm understanding your method correctly) be hitting the negative values? Like for example, I ran your method and after the second row,I calculated for array3[1][5] - 0.0126, but the output has 3.37 (ie: 1.97... -2 * 0.42190...)

Comment: I believe not, in the first example all the values are randomly generated between 5 and 30, and 5 is larger than the larger element in arr1 (4). So all the values should be positive

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding my comment to a full answer. The question is talking about two kinds of "repeat":

- Doable-in-parallel ones (column-wise, broadcast-able)
- Not-doable-in-parallel ones (row-wise, iterative)

`numpy` handles broadcast (i.e. column direction) nicely, so just use a for loop in row direction:

```
for i in range(len(array1)):
    array3[i+1] = (array3[i] - array1[i]) * array2[i]
```

Do notice `array3` should be longer than `array1` or `array2` otherwise that don't make sense.

**EDIT**

Oops I didn't see you want to avoid for loop. Technically you can do this problem without a for loop, but you need to mess up with linear algebra yourself:

If we name `array1` as `a`, `array2` as `b`, and the first row of `array3` as `c` for convenience. The rows of `array3` would be:

- `c`
- `(c-a0)*b0 = c*b0-a0*b0`
- `((c-a0)*b0-a1)*b1 = c*b0*b1-a0*b0*b1-a1*b1`
- ...

The final line of `array3` can then be computed as

```
B = b[::-1].cumprod(0)[::-1]
final_c = c * B[0] - (B * a).sum(0)
```

If you want the whole `array3`, that's not really trivial to do without for loop. You might be able to write it but that's both painful to read and painful to write. The performance is also questionable

Comment: I have no problem with  a loop, I just figured this might be able to be solved with another numpy function! As you said, I think it would be near impossible to do without a loop haha

Comment: It would be more simple if `numpy` provides a function that computes the "cumulative-product triangle" (i.e. a function that computes the cumulative product between any two points in an array and return a matrix)

Comment: Is there a module that you know of off the top of your head that provides that? Like I said, I'm not dead set on numpy or arrays for that matter, whatever provides an good easy solution I'm all for it!